# Why this object is a sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I whould like to know why $ \ \mathcal{C} : U \to \mathcal{C} ( U , \mathbb{R} ) $ is a sheaf ? $ U $ is an open set of $ E $ a $ \mathbb{R} $ - vector space which has a finite dimension.
$ \mathcal{C} ( U , \mathbb{R} ) $ contains continous maps over $ U $, with values in $ \mathbb{R} $. Thanks a lot.
P.S : sorry about my english language, i'm a foreign men from other country.   :-)

Comment: Have you tried checking the sheaf axioms? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I feel myself enable to establish the latest axiom which define what's a sheaf. More precisely, why is, if for avery open set $ V \subset E $ such that $ V = \displaystyle \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i $ : union of open sets, and $ (s_i )_{i \in I} $ sections over $ U_i $ checking : $ {s_{i}}_{|U_{i} \bigcap U_{j}} = {s_{j}}_{|U_{i} \bigcap U_{j}} $, then $ \exists ! s $ over $ V $ such that $ s_{|U_{i}} = s_i $ ?. So, my problem is to check the existence and the uniqueness. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually this is one of the motivating examples for the definition of a sheaf. A good(!) introduction to sheaves makes you know that this is a sheaf before giving the precise definition of a sheaf ...

Comment: Ok ! Thanks to yourself, i'll apply your advices. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proof goes mostly straightforward and this (nice functions with restriction of domain) is the "mother" example of all sheaves:
Given $V=\bigcup U_i$ and $s_i\colon U_i\to\mathbb R$ with $s_i|_{U_i\cap U_j}=s_j|_{U_i\cap U_j}$ for $i.j\in I$, define $s\colon V\to \mathbb R$ by letting 
$s(x)=s_i(x)$ where $i\in I$ is arbitrary with $x\in U_i$. Such $i$ exists because $x\in V=\bigcup U_i$. The function is welldefined because if we can pick another $j\in I$ with $x\in U_j$, then $s_i(x)=s_j(x)$.
Obviously $s|_{U_i}=s_i$ for all $i\in I$. This makes $s$ continuous for all $x\in U_i$, hence for all $x\in V$, i.e. $s$ is a section over $V$.

This $s$ is unique for if $s'\ne s$ then  $s'(x)\ne s(x)$ for some $x$, then for $U_i$ with $x\in U_i$, we have $s'|_{U_i}(x)\ne s|_{U_i}(x)$, hence $s'|_{U_i}\ne s|_{U_i}=s_i$.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot ! ^-^ It's so easy. but,  infortunatly,  i'm not enough strong at mathematics. Thank you again for having helped me. Thanks.  :-)

Comment: @Hagen:+1 for your accuracy. I have a question: is it true that a presheaf whose sections are actual functions is necessarily a sheaf?

Comment: @atricolf If, given a presheaf $P$ on a topological space $(X,\ \tau)$, by a section of $P$ you simply mean an element $s\in P(U)$ (where $U$ is some open subset of $X$) the answer is actually negative (in general). For example, take the presheaf $B_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}(-, \mathbb{R})$ which associates to every open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (endowed with the standard euclidean topology) the set of all *bounded* functions $U\longrightarrow X$. Convince yourself this is not a sheaf :)